# my laptop wont connect to the WiFi and i dont know if i can use a Ethernet dongle

Tags: drivers, wireless, ethernet

> i wiped my hardrive and i was use windows 8.1 and now my laptop wont connect to the WiFi. my laptop is the hp stream notebook 14 in new to Linux

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Are you usinig Ubuntu, which version?

Comment: im using 18.04.4